# Plesk preview link bassed on domain

Tags: dns, plesk

```
Hello every one i am trying to preview my sites through plesk upon domain linked to server
```

[Domain DNS Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxqzs.png)

```
i got this error
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8N7vr.png)
    and i am already manage dns from plesk
    How can i fix this error ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your site's DNS records were not propagated. Try to configure preview in Plesk >Tools & Settings > Website Preview as on [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/070py.png) or add record to your local hosts file.

Comment: how can i add this records please i am using centos 7

Comment: If you want to all local record, you should edit hosts file on your local workstation. Check [article](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213387909-Is-it-possible-to-access-a-domain-before-DNS-has-propagated-) for instructions.